# using recycler view in item of another recycler view with itemtouchhelper

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to use horizontal recycler view in the item of vertical recycler view but it uses ItemTouchHelper and when I trying to scroll child recycler view, parent item starting swiping instead of scrolling horizontal recycler view

how can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Disable swiping for parent recyclerview by not attaching an Itemtouchhelper.

Comment: I can't just remove swiping, I need to use it too

Comment: Well you have to decide for one of them, how else is your app supposed to know if you want to swipe or scroll in the nested recyclerview?